# The 'Claims' property on the 'Customer' type is not a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2, ef-model-first

I'm trying to add asp.net identity to my existing project.
I want to use the table "Customer" for users.

this is my Customer class :

```
public partial class Customer : IdentityUser<int, CustomerLogin, AspNetRole, CustomerClaim>
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Quotes = new HashSet<Quote>();
        this.Bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
        this.CustomerClaims = new HashSet<CustomerClaim>();
        this.CustomerLogins = new HashSet<CustomerLogin>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
    }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Customer, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }


    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    public override ICollection<CustomerClaim> Claims => this.CustomerClaims;
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerClaim> CustomerClaims { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerLogin> CustomerLogins { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

The first insertion pass, but when i attempt to inset a new user iget this error:

The 'Claims' property on the 'Customer' type is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method.

any idea ?

Comment: What happens when you don't override the `CustomerClaims` property?

Comment: The same error, i tried to override it in an attempt to resolve this error